# Conditional ternary without else

Tags: java

I have read the similar question and learnt that it is not possible to use a ternary operation instead of `if` statement, which does not have `else` statement. Because, `if-without else` statements are binary not ternary. My question is more best-practice.

In my code, there are lots of code snippet like that

```
  if( calculation < 1 ){
      calculation= 0;
    }
```

I would like to shorten these with tenary. Is it a good practice to change these statements with the following.

```
calculation = calculation < 1 ? 0 : calculation;
```

Comment: *"Is it a good practice..."* calls for opinion. Opinion-based questions are off-topic for SO.

Comment: And: No, it's not good practice. </opinion> ;-)

Comment: Does that ternary expression you suggest look shorter to you?

Comment: When we talk about performance, there is no difference. But for maintainability, if-else syntax is more future proof

Comment: Perhaps `calculationTo = Math.max(calculationTo,0);` would be more readable

Comment: @Eran it isn't, if I'm goin to look at it, I will think that there is additional logic underlying behind

Comment: @Eran That would change the logic. `0.5` should be replaced with `0`, but using `Math.max` it will stay as `0.5`.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I was under the assumption this variable is an int, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @AdInfinitum you could create a helper class(es) in the form of fluent API that would read something like this `calculationTo = replace(calculationTo).with(0).when(calculationTo < 1)`, but I am not sure if it looks much better.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak it is a good idea. If you change this to an answer, it will be accepted as solution :)

Comment: @Eran Your solution is also very good but this was just a sample and it should not be always max and I would like to get rid of all if statements.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder :) I did not like also this solution but in the logic, there are lots of such statements, which I do not like.

Comment: @AdInfinitum So your problem is not with if statements at all. It's about bad design that has resulted in all those if statements.

Comment: @Kayaman Your are right. I am learning everyday and when I look at the code design on the other day, I do not like the code and its design of previous day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a class (or classes) that would create a nice fluent API. Such that your line would be:

```
calculationTo = replace(calculationTo).with(0).when(calculationTo < 1)
```

In my opinion it doesn't read much better than a standard if statement, but it also depends on the conditions that you have.

Example implementation:

```
public class Replacer<T> {

    private final T value;
    private T replacementValue;

    private Replacer(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static <V> Replacer<V> replace(V value) {
        return new Replacer<V>(value);
    }

    public Replacer<T> with (T replacementValue) {
        this.replacementValue = replacementValue;
        return this;
    }

    public T when(boolean condition) {
        if (condition) {
            return replacementValue;
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
import static somepackage.Replacer.replace;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int calculationTo = 3;

        calculationTo = replace(calculationTo).with(0).when(calculationTo < 1);
    }

}
```

You might expand it or make condition a function so it can be used with lambda, etc. I would also make method `with` return object of different class (e.g. `ReplacerWithValue`) so that calling `with` twice in one chain would result in compilation error.

Comment: I think this solution is more self-explaining than just a simple if statement. If-else statement could be easy to write but not more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking for a best practice, I'll point out something where you could do better and then I'll tell you why I like the ternary operator.

Let me rephrase you're code snippet:

```
if (calculatedValueAfterStep1 < 1) {
    calculatedValueAfterStep2 = 0;
} else {
    calculatedValueAfterStep2 = calculatedValueAfterStep1;
}
```

When you read your code and somebody asks you "what does 'calculation' represent?" then you cannot answer this question without asking for the line number. The meaning of "calculation" changes over the course of the program code. If you cannot explain what a variable means, you cannot give it a good name. This is why I like my Version better. There is a clear Definition of what meaning the variables "calculatedValueAfterStep1" and "calculatedValueAfterStep2" are. Yes, the names are bad. Change them to your domain accordingly.

Now when you look at the code, you'll notice that "calculatedValueAfterStep2" is not declared. So let's Change the code:

```
int calculatedValueAfterStep2 = -1;
if (calculatedValueAfterStep1 < 1) {
    calculatedValueAfterStep2 = 0;
} else {
    calculatedValueAfterStep2 = calculatedValueAfterStep1;
}
```

Now it gets ugly. The same person asking the earlier question will now ask "why is 'calculatedValueAfterStep2' initialized with '-1'?". So here comes the ternary operator:

```
int calculatedValueAfterStep2 = (calculatedValueAfterStep1 < 1) ? 0 : calculatedValueAfterStep2;
```

beautiful!